# Correlation time of speckle pattern

Tags: optics, statistical-mechanics, scattering, correlation-functions, imaging

I am setting up classical ghost imaging. I am trying to reproduce the results [by this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/09500340500147240). It mentions that crucial things to get the experiment to work is spatial incoherence and measurement time must be much less than correlation time. The spatial incoherence can be generated by using a rotating ground glass and using a turbid medium. The correlation time depends upon the speed of rotation of the ground glass(Their correlation was about $100$ $ms$). I want to calculate the same for my experiment. How to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correlation time of the speckle pattern from a laser beam scattered by a rotating ground glass disk is derived in [[1](https://doi.org/10.1364/JOSA.61.001301)]. If the laser is focused on the ground glass, the first-order correlation simplifies to
$$\left| g^{(1)}(\tau) \right| = \exp{\left( -\frac{1}{2} {v_\text{rot}}^2 {\sigma_k}^2 \tau^2 \right)},$$
where $v_\text{rot}$ is the velocity of the disk at the position of the laser spot and $\sigma_k$ is the standard deviation of $k$-vectors contained in the ([Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam)) laser beam. It is related to the beam divergence $\theta = 2 \sigma_k \left/ \left| \vec{k} \right| \right.$. Using the [Siegert relation](https://doi.org/10.1140/epjd/s10053-022-00558-5), one obtains the second-order correlation function
$$g^{(2)}(\tau) = 1 + \left| g^{(1)}(\tau) \right|^2 = 1 + \exp{\left( -{v_\text{rot}}^2 {\sigma_k}^2 \tau^2 \right)} = 1 + \exp{\left( - \left( \frac{\tau}{\tau_c} \right)^2 \right)}$$
with a correlation time $\tau_c = \frac{1}{v_\text{rot} \sigma_k} = \frac{w_0}{v_\text{rot}}$, where $w_0$ is the beam waist of the laser.
[image]

So, if you need a longer coherence time in your experiment, you can rotate the disk slower or use a less strongly focused laser beam (increasing $w_0$). If you need even longer coherence times, you can also hold the disk still, acquire one data point, move the disk a bit, acquire the next data point, and so on. This is what was done in [this PhD thesis](https://nbn-resolving.org/urn:nbn:de:bvb:29-opus4-103280) (Ch. 3.1.1).

Comment: Does the relation change if we don't use a lens to focus it on the ground glass?

Comment: @QuantumOscillator As long as the waist of the laser beam is still on the ground glass, you can apply the same equations. They don't assume that the focusing is done by anything particular. If the waist is elsewhere, you have to go back to Eq. (13) of [[1](https://doi.org/10.1364/JOSA.61.001301)] and calculate the integral for the corresponding field distribution.